Синонимизировать метки на тему [домен]
Надо бы синонимизировать метки

domain (26 вопросов)
домен (189 вопросов)

описаний нет
Основная - конечно, домен, потому что она на русском.
PS: надо будет ещё сделать описание.

Интересно, что на енсо это синоним для dns

Готово!
updating post history, 27 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 26 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 24 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'domain': [domain] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 213
tag remapping of [домен] and [domain] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym domain -> домен was approved!

